# Avoiding repositioning of minipages when moving overlayed tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I'm fairly new to Beamer and stuck with this problem of two tikzpictures lying above two minipages. i want tikz1 to be displayed on slide 2 of the frame and tikz2 on the next slide (3). However they seem to take up space despite of the overlay argument. I've tried `\only` and `\visible`, but they too don't seem to work properly. When i move them, in some way the underlying minipages are moved and don't stay in the same place (which is what I desire)

With `\onslide`, moving one of the tikzpictures results in having the underlying elements all moved in the same way for all the slides.

With `\only` only the underlying elements of the current slide will be messed up, the other ones are not moved.

`\visible` seems to behave like `\onslide`.
But none of the above leave the minipages in the place where I want them to be.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=Goldenrod]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \item \uncover<1,3>{This cake is amazing and I am looking forward to eating it!}
  \item \uncover<1,2,3>{A friend prepared this cake yesterday.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \uncover<3>{n.a.}
  \item \uncover<2,3>{cake}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{minipage}


\onslide<2>{
\vspace*{-6.5cm}
\hspace*{7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay][remember picture]
    \node[align=center, ellipse callout, draw, callout relative pointer={(155:1cm)}, fill=yellow!30] (hallo) {some text};
        \end{tikzpicture}}

\onslide<3>{
\vspace*{-2cm}
\hspace*{7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay][remember picture]
    \node[align=center, ellipse callout, draw, callout relative pointer={(155:1cm)}, fill=yellow!30] (hallo) {some text};
        \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly do you want the callouts to appear? From your description, I thought you wanted them above the `minipage`s, but seing cmhughes's answer I am not so sure now.

Comment: Yea, they should appear above the minipages (or columns now) at changing positions and not take up space and not move the underlying contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would use `columns` for this, as they are `overlay` aware. In addition, you can use the tried and tested [`tikzmark`](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/beware-the-tikzmark-my-son/) idea (now available as a package) and used on this site in many, many examples :)

[image: animation]

I have `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to bump the nodes around a bit- you can tweak as you see necessary.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=Goldenrod]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 

\usepackage{tikz}
% tikzmark command, for shading over items
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}

\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{exampleblock}{}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \setbeamercovered{transparent}
                \item \uncover<1,3>{This cake is amazing and I am looking forward to eating it!}
                \item \uncover<1,2,3>{A friend prepared this cake yesterday.}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{exampleblock}{}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item \tikzmark{firstmark}\uncover<3>{n.a.} 
                \item \tikzmark{secondmark}\uncover<2,3>{cake}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}


\onslide<2>{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node[align=center, ellipse callout, draw, callout relative pointer={(155:1cm)}, fill=yellow!30] (hallo) at ($(firstmark)+(2,-1)$) {first bubble}; }

\onslide<3>{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node[align=center, ellipse callout, draw, callout relative pointer={(155:1cm)}, fill=yellow!30] (hallo) at ($(secondmark)+(2,-1)$) {hello world}; }



\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now that I see your code, I think I didn't understand the desired position for the callouts.

Comment: That works out for me! Even though the callouts still behaved weirdly at some points, bumping each other around. But in the end it seems to be stable now.

The main problem might have been the minipages or the h- and v-spaces that cause the mess up. The tikzmark command works good!

Comment: And overlay aware therefore means that the columns as opposed to the minipages will not be affected by the movement of things on top of them?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, that's what I meant by `overlay` aware :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need (at least in this example code) to use `remember picture, overlay`. You can simply use the fact that `\node` is overlay aware:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=Goldenrod]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,every node/.style={align=center, ellipse callout, draw, callout relative pointer={(155:1cm)}, fill=yellow!30}]
    \node<2> at (.5\textwidth,0) (hallo) {some text};
    \node<3> at (.5\textwidth,0) (hallo) {some other text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \item \uncover<1,3>{This cake is amazing and I am looking forward to eating it!}
  \item \uncover<1,2,3>{A friend prepared this cake yesterday.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \uncover<3>{n.a.}
  \item \uncover<2,3>{cake}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]